# How to prevent ternary operator indentation in swiftlint?

Tags: conditional-operator, swiftlint

I want to break the ternary operator into separate lines like this:

```
first < second
? return 1
: return 2
```

But the SwiftLint configurations always tries to add extra indentation like this:

```
first < second
    ? return 1
    : return 2
```

I want to stop this default behaviour and tried the following with no luck:

```
indentation:
  conditional_indentation: none
```

So how can I prevent this? Or even better, how can I force the first style for the automatic formatter?

Thanks in advanced.